# POP3 server not Connect with client. Is there any way to Connect using c#?

Tags: c#, authentication, pop3, email-client, mail-server

While am trying connect, the client is not connecting, the password and username are correct.
We have using this same code for a long and it's works.
Is there any security update from Outlook.

(POP3 server not Connect with client. Is there any way to Connect using c#?)

```
MailServer oServer = new MailServer("pop-mail.outlook.com", "mail@domain.com", "Password", true, ServerAuthType.AuthLogin, ServerProtocol.Pop3);

MailClient oClient = new MailClient("MYKEY");
Thread.Sleep(1000);

oClient.Connect(oServer);

List\<MailInfo\> allMails = oClient.GetMailInfos().ToList\<MailInfo\>();
```

Needed to connect the client to the server

Comment: Most emails require credentials and not a username password since credentials are encrypted.

Comment: outlook.com is no longer accepting a username and password for authentication. You need to use OAUTH2.